# Correct way to split nested brackets in PHP, e.g. "root[one[a,b,c],two[d,e,f]]" into array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing, split

Like the title says it I'm looking for a robust way to parse this expression into an array (example in code).

```
<?php

$str = 'root[one[a,b,c],two[d,e,f]]'
$decoded = decode($str);
```

Output:

```
$decoded = ['root' => ['one' => ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'two' => ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

I'm trying to do it via Regex but it since the brackets and commas are nested it's not yielding the correct results. How can I do this?

Comment: Make it valid JSON and you can simply use `json_decode()`

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion.. it did come into my mind since the expression looks like JSON but unfortunately it has to be modified a lot before it can be parsed by json_decode.. i can give it a try, but do you think it's the best idea to use that way?

Comment: It will probably be the easiest way, so I would give it a try and when you get stuck just post the current progress here and we will help you.

Comment: Never use regex to parse something! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions

Comment: @Rizier123: I was able to create a PHP array but can't figure out a way to transform it into json (because json uses both square and curly brackets so can't figure how to replace them properly).. can you help me write the same using json_decode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple parser below should do the job. I did not test it much - only a successful route, and few obvious edge cases based on fair assumptions.

```
var_dump(parse('root[one[a,b,c],two[d,e,f]]'));

function parse($str, $level = 0) {
    if ($level === 0) {
        // strip spaces once for simplicity
        $str = str_replace([" ", "\t"], '', $str);
    }
    $result = [];
    while(true) {
        $rest = strpbrk($str, '[],');
        if (!$rest) {
            if (strlen($str) > 0) {
                throw new ExpectedEndOfStringException($str);
            }
            return $result;
        }
        $term = substr($rest, 0, 1);
        $rest = substr($rest, 1);
        $val = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $term));
        switch ($term) {
            case '[':
                if (!$val) {
                    $val = 0;
                } elseif (isset($result[$val])) {
                    throw new NonUniqueKeyException($val);
                }
                list($a, $str) = parse($rest, $level+1);
                if (is_null($a) && is_null($str)) {
                    throw new BracketsMismatchException($rest);
                }
                $result = array_merge($result, [$val => $a]);
                break;
            case ']':
                if ($val) {
                    $result[] = $val;
                }
                if($level < 1) {
                    throw new BracketsMismatchException($rest);
                }
                if (strlen($rest) > 0 && !in_array(substr($rest, 0, 1), [',', ']'])) {
                    throw new MalformedStringException($val.$term.$rest);
                }
                return [$result, ltrim($rest, ',')];
            case ',':
                if (!$val) {
                    throw new UnexpectedComaException($term.$rest);
                }
                $result[] = $val;
                $str = $rest;
                break;
            default:
                throw new LogicException();
        }
    }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1e74494226d530d1ed5b3c2d0fd7d545acb2d9e

You will need to implement all the exception classes, but it should be trivial. Otherwise just replace them with generic `\Exception();`

Comment: this is awesome.. the best thing about this is that if someday the syntax changes (curly brackets, etc) then it should be easy to accommodate those changes (may not possible with the other approach).

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestions by @Rizier123, here it the code I was able to create

```
<?php

$str = 'root[one[a,b,c],two[d,e,f]]';
$str = preg_replace('/\[/', '=> [', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(\w+)/', "'\\1'", $str);

eval("\$code = [$str];");
print "<pre>"; print_r($code); exit;
```

And it seems to be working! Thanks for the help.

Output: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4921d1403f2b4030db8ecb8c16b04aa4636eedd

Comment: It uses `eval` unfortunately, so I'm still all ears if anybody has a better idea.. thanks!